# Is there any known result for 1-median problem with negative weights in Euclidean space?

Tags: ds.algorithms, cg.comp-geom

> Given a set of $n$ points $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ in $R^d$, find a point $p$
>   such that $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i d(p,v_i)$ is minimized, where $w_i$ is the
>   weight of $v_i$, which may be  positive or negative.

Is there any known result for this problem. It seems the problem has been considered in graphs ([one](http://rutcor.rutgers.edu/~do99/EA/ECela.ps), [two](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10878-008-9187-4)). What about in $R^d$ ?  Due to the negative weights, the problem is not convex any more.

Comment: Hi Jian ! can you provide a link for the statement that "the problem has been considered in graphs" ?

Comment: Here are two examples: http://rutcor.rutgers.edu/~do99/EA/ECela.ps  http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10878-008-9187-4

Comment: thanks. added them inline. It sounds like an interesting open problem.

Comment: hmmm, I think we need some sort of constraints or more info: Consider the case where all weights are negative.

Comment: It would be great if the algorithm can tell us whether the solution is unbounded (like some linear programming algorithm).

Comment: The way the problem statement is written, $p$ does not necessarily have to be one of $\nu_1 \ldots \nu_n$ (so it looks like a 'mean' problem rather than a 'median' problem) ?